# Reorder chunks string

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I've got a string in log coming from Windows

```
 InstallDate=20171026224422.000000+300
```

How can I extract date and time from this string with sed and represent them as human readable format? I mean `10/26/2017 22:44:22` My vision of solution for date (pseudo):

```
 sed -nr 's/.*=([0-9]{1,4})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2}).*/\2/\\1/\\3/p'
```

But it's pseudo, not a real solution (at last it looks very awful). How to capture chunks of a string and reorder them after?

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more pretty way to do this with sed

```
sed -nr "s|.*=(.{4})(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..).*|\2/\3/\1 \4:\5:\6|p"
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues in your sed command, following should work:

```
sed -nr 's/.*InstallDate=([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*/\2\/\3\/\1/p' <input.txt
```

or with time

```
sed -nr 's/.*InstallDate=([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*/\2\/\3\/\1 \4:\5:\6/p' <input.txt
```

- the `/` must be escaped as regex delimiter (note that other delimiters can also be used for example `s,,,` or `s@@@` etc.)
- the backreferences must be escaped with only one `\` (`\1`, not `\\1`)
- the order of backreference was wrong
- note the `.*` at the beginning and the end to make the regex match the whole line remove all other characters

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be a puzzle solving contest. Use awk!

```
$ cat r.sh
awk '
/InstallDate/ {
    sub(/InstallDate=/, "")
    sub(/\..*/, "")
    ya = nxt(4); mo = nxt(2); da = nxt(2)
    ho = nxt(2); mi = nxt(2); se = nxt(2)
    printf "%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s\n", mo, da, ya, ho, mi, se
}
function nxt(i,   s) { s = substr($0, 1, i); $0 = substr($0, i + 1); return s}
'
```

Usage

```
 $ echo InstallDate=20171026224422.000000+300 | sh r.sh
 10/26/2017 22:44:22
```

See documentation for `substr` and `sub`.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html

Answer (score -1):

Your `sed` does the job, once you remove all the `1,` specifiers. Those fields are fixed-width.